# Generate png images with GD Library and add them to a zip archive

Tags: php, png, php-ziparchive

I would like to generate multiple *.png* images and add them to a zip archive for download.

I'm using the **GD LIBRARY** and **ZipArchive**

The images are a combination of text and pictures coming from a *foreach loop* of a query.

A snippet is worth a thousand words

```
require_once '../gd_imagestyle.php';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {

 foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) { 

  $foto = "../photos/".$row['foto'];
  $ext = pathinfo($foto, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

  $my_img = imagecreatetruecolor( 400, 250 );
  $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 0 );

  if($ext == "png"){ // PICTURES CAN BE .png or .jpg
   $thumbnail = imagecreatefrompng($foto);
  }else{
   $thumbnail = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto);
  }

  $tinypic = imagestyle($thumbnail, 'autosize:105 105'); // RESIZE THE PICTURE
  imagecopy($my_img, $tinypic, 270, 85, 0, 0, 105, 105);   // INSERT THE PICTURE
  imagestring( $my_img, 2, 20, 65, "First and last name", $text_colour );
  imagestring( $my_img, 2, 20, 120, "Birthplace", $text_colour );

  imagecolorallocate( $text_color );
  // header( "Content-type: image/png" );  // I COMMENTED THIS PART  SINCE I WANT A ZIP FILE BACK

  imagestring( $my_img, 5, 120, 65, $row['lastname'].' '.$row['firstname'], $text_colour );
  imagestring( $my_img, 5, 120, 120, $row['birthplace'], $text_colour );

  $singleImage = imagepng( $my_img );
  imagedestroy( $my_img );

  $zip->addFile($singleImage, 'newname'.$i.'.png');  // 

  $i++;

 } // END FOREACH

 $zip->close();
} // END ZipArchive

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
```

The server presents an empty .zip (I call this via ajax from another page). What am I not considering?

Thank you

Inve

Comment: I believe ZipArchive needs an actual file in order to write it. You probably need to output the image to a temp directory and then add it.

Comment: @JeremyHarris thank you for your comment, I will give it a try and report later

Comment: Thank you @JeremyHarris, I edited my code at imagepng() like:

_imagepng( $my_img,'./tmp/temporarypic'.$i.'.png');_

and then reiterate the $zip->addFile with the content of the temporary directory.

It works!

Comment: Awesome, I will add it as an answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZipArchive does not support adding an image stream. You need to write the file to a temporary location and then add it to the zip:

```php
$tempPath = '/tmp/';
$i = 0;

foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $imgStream = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 250);
    // ...more image manipulation of the stream
    $filePath = $tempPath.'temp'.$i.'.png';
    $img = imagepng($imgStream, $filePath);
    $zip->addFile($filePath, 'newfile'.$i.'.png');
    $i++;
}
```